# move position labels of bar, to maximize / minimize the screen, the text unsettle ( in C3.js - D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I made a chart bar, in c3.js adding modifications d3.js.
I want the text of the bars this at the beginning of each bar, then do it with the following code in d3.js.
[image]

```
d3.selectAll('.c3-text')
   .each(function(d){
   var self = d3.select(this);
   self.attr('x', '5');
});
```

the problem is when I move the window. It unsettles the text.the text appears by default to the right, as initially. [image]

What I can do to fix it?
thank you very much.

https://jsfiddle.net/ezd1ggwa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move all the d3 activities to move text into a resize function like this:

```
function resize() {

  d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick')
    .each(function(d, i) {
      // clear tick contents and replace with image
      var self = d3.select(this);
      //  self.selectAll("*").remove();
      self.append('image')
        .attr("xlink:href", arrayOfPics[i])
        .attr("x", -40)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("width", 25)
        .attr("height", 25);
    });

  d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick')
    .each(function(d, i) {
      // clear tick contents and replace with image
      var self = d3.select(this);
      //  self.selectAll("*").remove();
      self.append('text')
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", -110)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("this text is a indicator");
    });
  d3.select('.c3-axis-x').attr("clip-path", null);

  d3.selectAll('.c3-text')
    .each(function(d) {
      var self = d3.select(this);
      self.attr('x', '5');
    });

}
```

Now on chart resize call this function like this:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  size: {
    height: 500,
   }
   ....
  onresized: function() {//callback called on resize of a chart
    resize()
  }
});
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yLcv5r20/1/)

Comment: thank you very much, I had tried something, but look at the text that says "this text is an indicator" is overwritten.

Comment: You should remove it before appending `self.selectAll("text").remove();` new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mgkkkdo4/

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I am developing this mobile version. and in some cases must reload the entire chart, and in no time the chart is rescaled and the same problem happens. you know that can happen?

Comment: I am sorry for mobiles :(

Comment: I mean that when it generates the graph again some event should shoot to put the changes I need in d3.js. again

Comment: can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974517/put-axis-label-y-in-multiline-for-long-texts-in-c3-js-d3-js